# SQL update two different server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have two SQL server [example]:

1. 1st - 10.101.102.133
2. 2nd - 10.101.102.155

Both having the same database with same names and fields.

My application will update in the 1st server.

Can I actually configure the 1st server that once it received update query, it will update in 2nd server as well?

I do not wish to change my application source code but instead want to make configuration on the server itself.

Comment: Use `SQL Server Replication`. https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/synchronize-sql-server-databases-in-different-remote-sources/

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956985/synchronize-sql-server-databases

Comment: Do you really use sql server (which is a Microsoft product), or mysql? You tagged both...